# What is the difference between pauseAWT() and sleepAWT()

Tags: java, awt

Can anyone help me with the difference between pauseAWT() and awtSleep()? Also when to use one over other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`junit.extensions.jfcunit.JFCTestCase` in the AWT testing stuff of JUnit? I think the [Javadocs](http://jfcunit.sourceforge.net/api/junit/extensions/jfcunit/JFCTestCase.html#pauseAWT%28%29) are pretty clear:

- **`pauseAWT`:** Pause the awt event queue until it is released by `releaseAWT()` or the end of the test is reached.
- **`awtSleep`:**  **w/o argument:** Suspends the test for up to a maximum period of time, and allows the AWT Thread to resume temporarily / **w/ argument:** Suspends the test for up to the specified (maximum) period of time, and allows the AWT Thread to resume temporarily.

So, the first pauses the AWT thread, the second pauses the test and allows the AWT thread to resume. Bear in mind that AWT operates in a separate thread, commonly called the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread). It looks like you would use these two methods in tandem to ensure a replicable state for testing.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's because sometimes the AWT thread might run code at the same time as your code (if you put stuff onto the AWT thread at the same time). Because the two execute in tandem in different ways, it becomes hard to test. So this lets you have only one thread executing at any point to make it the same every time.

Comment: what exactly does releaseAWT() do?

Comment: Unpauses the AWT thread. The test is able to pause and unpause the AWT event thread execution with `pauseAWT` / `releaseAWT` respectively, but `awtSleep()` can pause the test thread (presumably you could do the same with `Thread.sleep()`, but in that case there may be a race condition between re/starting the AWT thread and pausing the current thread execution, and may lead to execution runs being more difficult to replicate. The single statement wraps the intended synchronisation barrier.